# How to add all layers to OpenLayers from a single GeoServer WMS?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wms

I want to add all layers to OpenLayers from a single GeoServer WMS. I tried this but it didn't work for me:

```
<script>
  var layers = [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),

    new ol.layer.Image({
     
      source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
        url: 'http://localhost/geoserver/wmsExamples/wms?',
        params: {'LAYERS': '*'},
        ratio: 1,
        serverType: 'geoserver'
      })
    })

  ];
  
</script>
```

Comment: Seems to be duplicate. Is this what you are looking for? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/70521/67659

Answer (score 2):

You need to [request and parse](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wms-capabilities.html) the `getCapabilities` document from your server,

```
import 'ol/ol.css';
import WMSCapabilities from 'ol/format/WMSCapabilities';
var parser = new WMSCapabilities();

fetch('data/ogcsample.xml')
  .then(function (response) {
    return response.text();
  })
  .then(function (text) {
    var result = parser.read(text);
    document.getElementById('log').innerText = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);
  });
```

This will give you a JSON object that contains all the layers, then you need their names to use in your `ImageWMS` request.

Comment: I actually tried that code , it gives a cros origin error , even  I can render the WMS on the map, just I wanna hint to this , I noticed all get WMSCapabilities code use different url not like the wms url is that matters ? if so how to get such a url from geoserver. actually the url I put in the fetch statement is the wms one which not ends with xml or json.

Comment: in your case it would be `http://localhost/geoserver/wmsExamples/wms?request=getCapabilities&service=wms&version=1.1.0` as for cors error there are many questions on how to solve that depending on how you are running GeoServer